# Sitecore 8.2 Separate Processing Server

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am using Sitecore 8.2 Update 6. Earlier my CM, Processing and Reporting roles are on single CM server. Now I just need to use separate Processing server and my Reporting and CM will be on one server.

I have configured my processing server as mentioned in the following url:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_processing_server

and configured my connection strings as per the following url:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/database_connection_strings_for_configuring_servers

Now I have couple of questions:

1) IS there any change required in my CM or CD to know about my separate processing server

2) How can I test whether my processing server is doing the required tasks.

Thanks,

Nicks

Answer (score 1):

Your CM and CD do not need to know about the processing server, but you need to make sure that processing functions are not enabled on the CM or CD.

You will know if processing is working by looking at the logs and seeing if the pipelines are executing and not throwing errors.

You will also see analytics data being processed and showing up in the reporting database. If you are not seeing analytics data, this is an indication you might have errors in processing.

Note that there are several possible reasons reporting data might not be working, but if it is succeeding at getting your new analytics data than processing is running.